# ValueError: Cannot query "": Must be "Group" instance. Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Добавил пользователя в django с правами на просмотр групп и шкафчиков. После этого вышел с админки и решил зайти под этим пользователем, дабы посмотреть, как будет выглядеть. Сразу же, после авторизации вылетела такая ошибка:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Django Version: 5.0.1
Python Version: 3.11.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'backend',
 'userapp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 259, in wrapper
    return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 188, in _view_wrapper
    result = _process_exception(request, e)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 186, in _view_wrapper
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 80, in _view_wrapper
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 240, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 553, in index
    app_list = self.get_app_list(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 537, in get_app_list
    app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request, app_label)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 479, in _build_app_dict
    has_module_perms = model_admin.has_module_permission(request)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 636, in has_module_permission
    return request.user.has_module_perms(self.opts.app_label)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 331, in has_module_perms
    return _user_has_module_perms(self, app_label)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 235, in _user_has_module_perms
    if backend.has_module_perms(user, app_label):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 117, in has_module_perms
    for perm in self.get_all_permissions(user_obj)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 105, in get_all_permissions
    user_obj._perm_cache = super().get_all_permissions(user_obj)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 24, in get_all_permissions
    *self.get_group_permissions(user_obj, obj=obj),
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 99, in get_group_permissions
    return self._get_permissions(user_obj, obj, "group")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 80, in _get_permissions
    perms = getattr(self, "_get_%s_permissions" % from_name)(user_obj)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 64, in _get_group_permissions
    return Permission.objects.filter(**{user_groups_query: user_obj})
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1476, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1494, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1501, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1602, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1634, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
                                 
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1521, in build_filter
    self.check_related_objects(join_info.final_field, value, join_info.opts)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1335, in check_related_objects
    self.check_query_object_type(value, opts, field)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programs\OSPanel\domains\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1312, in check_query_object_type
    raise ValueError(
    ^

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/
Exception Value: Cannot query "": Must be "Group" instance.
```

Скорее всего это связано с тем, что я дополнял группы доп. полями.
Мой admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your backend here.
from userapp.models import User, WardrobeEvent, CardRental, Wardrobe, Section, MyGroup, GroupAdmin, WardrobeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import GroupAdmin as BaseGroupAdmin

admin.site.site_header = "Администраторская панель"


class GroupInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MyGroup
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = "Уровень доступа и описание"


class GroupInlineAdd(BaseGroupAdmin):
    inlines = (GroupInline,)


# admin.site.register(User)
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("username", "email", "groups", "last_login")


admin.site.unregister(Group)

admin.site.register(WardrobeEvent)
admin.site.register(CardRental)


@admin.register(Wardrobe)
class WardrobeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = WardrobeForm


admin.site.register(Section)

admin.site.register(Group, GroupInlineAdd)
admin.site.register(GroupAdmin)
```

Мой models.py:

```
import random
import string

from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, Group
from backend.models import AccessLevel, Card
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminTextInputWidget
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


# Create your backend here.
class MyGroup(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField(to=Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, primary_key=True)
    access_level = models.ForeignKey(to=AccessLevel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Group"
        verbose_name = "Группа"
        verbose_name_plural = "Группы"


class User(AbstractUser):
    groups = models.ForeignKey(to=MyGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=2)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.password = make_password(self.password)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        db_table = "User"
        verbose_name = "Пользователь"
        verbose_name_plural = "Пользователи"
        ordering = ("username", "email")


class GroupAdmin(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default=0)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "GroupAdmin"
        verbose_name = "Администратор группы"
        verbose_name_plural = "Администраторы групп"


class Section(models.Model):
    required_access_level = models.ForeignKey(to=AccessLevel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Section"
        verbose_name = "Секция"
        verbose_name_plural = "Секции"


class Wardrobe(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(to=Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    mac = models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=True, default="00:00:00:00:00:00")
    secret = models.CharField(max_length=256, default="a" * 64, editable=False)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            salt = random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=16)
            self.secret = make_password(self.secret, salt)

        super().save(**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Wardrobe"
        verbose_name = "Шкафчик"
        verbose_name_plural = "Шкафчики"


class WardrobeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address = forms.GenericIPAddressField(widget=AdminTextInputWidget(attrs={'placeholder': 'Введите IP-адрес'}))
    mac = forms.CharField(max_length=17, validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$',
                                                                    message="Введите MAC-адрес в формате XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX")],
                          widget=AdminTextInputWidget(attrs={'placeholder': 'Введите MAC-адрес'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Wardrobe
        fields = "__all__"
```

Группы в базе данных:

[image: auth_group]

Моя доп. таблица group:

[image: Group]